# Python - Efficient way to find the largest area of a specific value in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D numpy array where some values are zero, and some are not. I'm trying to find an efficient way to find the biggest clump of zeros in the array (by returning the number of zeros, as well as a rough idea of where the center is)

For example in this array, I would like to find the clump of 9, with the center of (3,4):

```
[[ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
 [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
 [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
 [ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]]
```

Is there a nice vectorized way to accomplish something like this in numpy or scipy?

The clumps will be roughly circular in shape, and have no holes in them.

[ndimage.label()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) from scipy does something close to this, but isn't quite what I'm after. I have a feeling [numpy.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [numpy.diff()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) could be helpful, but not sure how to efficiently use them to solve this problem.

Comment: What if there is a hole? Are you saying there will be no holes because you know something about what the input looks like, or because you want to exclude clumps with holes in them?

Comment: It's because I know that the input will not have any holes (and if so, they will be extremely rare)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to combine `ndimage.label` with `numpy.bincount`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

array = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(200, 200))

label, num_label = ndimage.label(array == 0)
size = np.bincount(label.ravel())
biggest_label = size[1:].argmax() + 1
clump_mask = label == biggest_label
```

Once you have `clump_mask` you can compute the centroid or use some other method to get the center.

Comment: It is *insane* how close this is to what I was about to paste!  The only things I did differently were (1) `.ravel().astype(int)`, because I was getting complaints about converting from `uint32` to `int32`, and (2) I added (changing variable names to match yours) `com = scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass(array == 0, label, biggest_label)` to get the centre.

Comment: adventofcode player thanks you!