# Find the most "empty" place in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Let's say that I've the following numpy array:

```
foo = np.asarray([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
])
```

As you can see, it contains some 0 et 1. I'm searching for the most "empty" place in this array. I mean the place where you find the higher density of 0. I would like to do a function that return me the row and col index of the center of that place.

For the moment what I tried to do is to cut that array in four parts of the same size with a function like this :

```
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    """Return an array of shape (n, nrows, ncols)."""
    h, w = arr.shape
    arr = arr.reshape(h // nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
    arr = arr.swapaxes(1, 2)
    arr = arr.reshape(-1, nrows, ncols)

    return (arr)
```

Then I compute the sum of each part. Take the cut where the sum was the lowest and cut in again in 4, and so on... But I feel it's not the right things to...

Comment: are you looking for the largest area where the sum of the adjacent elements is 0, or a specific shape that this 'place' has to be? Because if not you could return any element with a 0, and it will have the highest possible density

Comment: You will need to define centre, because the centre is a concave shape may be outside the shape

Comment: the largest area with zero

Comment: @OlivierMelançon arg, yes, it's hard to define : (

Comment: what do you mean by area, please be more specific

Comment: Mmm, that dupe asks basically the same question as you, has an accepted answer but sort of hand-waves the "center finding" part.

Comment: Maybe closest point to center?

Comment: @roganjosh I'm checking if this is really what I'm searching for but it looks good : )

Comment: I'm trying to work out how to finish it off. The dupe is close and I've left it tagged but I'm not really happy with how it just ends so I'm trying to work out the completion step

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I didn't thinked about this weird case where the center is outside, could we assume that the shapes look almost like a circle or ellipse ?

Comment: If your shape is convexe, then the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basically borrowing the code from [Efficient way to find the largest area of a specific value in a 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110364/4799172) but it stops short of finding (or at least, a definition of) the center. For that, we can use `ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

foo = np.asarray([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
])

label, num_label = ndimage.label(foo == 0)
size = np.bincount(label.ravel())
biggest_label = size[1:].argmax() + 1
clump_mask = label == biggest_label

center = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(clump_mask)
```

This gives: `(7.238095238095238, 6.571428571428571)`

Comment: works perfectly for my needs : )