# How to find the largest area in a given matrix and return its position/boundries

Tags: python, arrays

Im trying to implement the [maze generation recursive division algorithm](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm), and in my implementation im getting stuck in one of the major parts of said algorithm.

Suppose I have a matrix like this

```
[
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
]
```

Here i want to be able to find the largest area of `'0'` in the matrix and return its starting and ending points which in this case will be `[0][3] to [4][4]` and i there should be a way to figure out if it is breadth-wise big or length-wise big so i can again use the same function for this particular area for example, since it is length-wise big it makes a random line on said area and divides it and the function repeates

```
[
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
]
```

[I found a similar answer but I cant find out how to implement that to my situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110232/python-efficient-way-to-find-the-largest-area-of-a-specific-value-in-a-2d-nump)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are only interested in square areas of 0, you can build on the answer you linked like so:

```
from scipy import ndimage

label, num_label = ndimage.label(matrix == '0')
size = np.bincount(label.ravel())
biggest_label = size[1:].argmax() + 1
clump_mask = label == biggest_label

a, b = np.where(clump_mask)
coordinates = (a[0], b[0]), (a[-1], b[-1])

((0, 3), (4, 4))
```

Then if you want to know if it's bigger length or width-wise, you can use your coordinates:

```
if (abs(coordinates[0][0] - coordinates[1][0]) > 
    abs(coordinates[0][1] - coordinates[1][1])):
    bigger = 'length'
else:
    bigger = 'width'
```

Comment: For this to work I need to convert my matrix to an np array right? also thanks for your reply!

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can call np.array() on your matrix and that should work.

Comment: ok I'll try it out and inform if it works or not, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted almost gives out the solution.

Here is what you can do:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

# Your matrix
array = np.array([
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
])

# Finds the contiguous locations (labels) of '0' elements
label, num_label = ndimage.label(array == '0')
size = np.bincount(label.ravel())
biggest_label = size[1:].argmax() + 1

# Gets the extreme point locations of the biggest area
seq = np.arange(array.size).reshape(array.shape)
_, _, start, stop = ndimage.extrema(seq, label, index=biggest_label)
```

`start` and `stop` would now hold the coordinates of the extreme points of the biggest patch, which for this example would be (0, 3) and (4, 4).